Ошибка new ServerSelectionError() при обращении фронта к api сайта на Docker
Есть фулстек приложение сайта (React, Node, Mongo). Я его докеризирую.
//docker-compose.yml

services:
 web:
   build: ./movies-explorer-frontend
   depends_on:
     - api
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   networks:
     - network-backend
 api:
   build: ./movies-explorer-api
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   ports:
     - "3001:3001"
   networks: 
    - network-backend
 
 mongo:
   image: mongo
   restart: always
   volumes: 
     - mongodb_data:/data/db
     - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   environment: 
     MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
     MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
   networks: 
    - network-backend

networks:
 network-backend:

volumes: 
 mongodb_data:

//mongo-init.js

db=db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.auth('root','root')
db=db.getSiblingDB('bitfilmsdb')
db.createUser({
    'user': "user",
    'pwd': "user",
    'roles': [{
        'role': 'dbOwner',
        'db': 'bitfilmsdb'
    }]
})
db.createCollection('movies');
db.createCollection('users')

Из строки подключения к БД в api убрал localhost (вероятная причина ошибки), стало:
const { DB_PATH = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/bitfilmsdb' } = process.env;

При первом обращении фронта к api контейнер api все равно останавливается с ошибкой:
/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847
2024-05-25 14:53:07   const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();

Подскажите, какая еще может быть причина?
Дополнение: при тестировании контейнера БД локально, запустив по отдельности бэк и фронт через VS Code в терминале увидел, что для моей сети вместо localhost используется другой ip (не 127.0.0.1). Поменяв строку подключения к БД все заработало. Видимо это ip, который присваивает оператор, так как он постоянно меняется. Но тогда как сделать универсальное решение для любого компьютера?

Решил проблему через назначение статического ip для контейнера mongo с помощью встроенной DNS-службы Docker, как указано в ссылке:
https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-communicating-with-containers-on-same-machine
//docker-compose.yml

services:
  web:
    build: ./movies-explorer-frontend
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - network-backend
  api:
    build: ./movies-explorer-api
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    networks: 
     - network-backend
  
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
      - ./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment: 
      MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks: 
      network-backend:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2

networks:
  network-backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.5.0.1
          
volumes: 
  mongodb_data:

